# Answer accepted on a former-tumbleweed question will receive +20 reputation

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, tumbleweed-badge

### The goal:

**reduce the number of tumbleweeds in SO**. Sure, some of the questions are hopeless due to them being unclear, unreadable, or just too general, but some just got forgotten for no good reason.

### The means:

Each [tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed) that will eventually get an accepted answer will **reward the answering user +5 rep** more than a usual accepted answer.

Furthermore, I think we need to draw more attention to tumbleweeds, by linking to the tumbleweed page from the main SO page.

Answer (score 4):

1. Revival and necromancer badges seem to target the same problem already.
2. Maybe it's just me, but additional 5 points for accepted answer isn't gonna change my behaviour in any way. If a tumbleweed question in the area of my knowledge poped up into my face, I would answer it even now. But I'm not gonna start trawling question archive for the lousy 5 reputation points.

I do agree, though, that bringing tumbleweeds more efficiently to people's attention might help. (but how to do it is a tricky question, as we already have some tools to access old questions)

My two cents.

Comment: Good points. Still, it saddens me that there are so many tumbleweeds (14 in the last 4h), most of them (11/14) by users with rep below 10 (AKA newcomers). **This could drive them out of SO community**. Do you have suggestions to achieve this goal otherwise?

Comment: @HuBeZa Actually, before today I didn't give much attention to 'unanswered' tab at all :) Now, that I know of its existence, I'll try it and see how good it is.